# How to solve this integer array sort not working as intended?

Tags: java, arrays

Tried doing this but still doesn't sort to ascending order.
The purpose of this method is to take in an integer array and create a new integer array with the values of the input integer array. The newly created array is then to be sorted. But it seems this method of sorting does not work.

```
private static int[] getSortAscend(int[] inputArray) {
    int sortArray[] = inputArray;
    int lngth = sortArray.length;
    
    for(int m = 0; m < lngth; m++) {
        for(int p = m+1; p < lngth; p++) {
            if(sortArray[m] > sortArray[p]) {
                int temp = sortArray[m];
                sortArray[m] = sortArray[p];
                sortArray[p] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return sortArray;
}
```

Comment: Can you show an example input and output please? Are you only sorting the array?

Comment: `int sortArray[] = inputArray;` doesn't create a *new array*; it just shares a *reference* to `inputArray`.

Comment: Heck I have been staring and retyping the same thing over and over again for hours now making sure I was not doing something wrong. Turns out it was about reference.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably due to you doing `int sortArray[] = inputArray;`, your `sortArray` points to the input one, and since you're modifying it, your algorithm will not work (since numbers will keep changing).

Try this:

```
private static int[] getSortAscend(int[] inputArray) {
    int lngth = sortArray.length;
    int sortArray[] = inputArray.clone();
    
    for(int m = 0; m < lngth; m++) {
        for(int p = m+1; p < lngth; p++) {
            if(sortArray[m] > sortArray[p]) {
                int temp = sortArray[m];
                sortArray[m] = sortArray[p];
                sortArray[p] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return sortArray;
}
```

Comment: you have to *copy* `inputArray` items into `sortedArray`

Comment: Thanks to the answers. Figured it out. Have to copy the contents with for loop.

Answer (score 0):

when you setting `int sortArray[] = inputArray;` it doesn't create a new array just making a references to the same array. also to mention you don't need to get length of array separately you can just invoke `sortArray.length` to get the length:

```
private static int[] getSortAscend(int[] inputArray) {
    int sortArray[] = inputArray.clone();
    for (int m = 0; m < sortArray.length; m++) {
        for (int p = m + 1; p < sortArray.length; p++) {
            if (sortArray[m] > sortArray[p]) {
                int temp = sortArray[m];
                sortArray[m] = sortArray[p];
                sortArray[p] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
    return sortArray;
}
```